# Get a match except if text is not shown behind

Tags: python, regex

In my Python system i'm trying to grab information about materials and split them up accordingly. However i'm having a hard time isolating a text and using a negative lookbehind as it seems it has no effect.

**Current Regex**

```
(?:(?P<value>\d+)[%\s]*?)?(?<!sock)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z\s\(\)\-\™\,\®]+)
```

**Test Strings**

| Strings |
| --- |
| Leather |
| Sock Leather |
| 100% Cotton |
| 100Cot |
| 80Cot20Pol |
| Sock 100 Leather |
| Sock 100% Leather |
| 80 % Polyester, 20 % Cotton |
| 5% Cotton, 20% Polyester, 50% Cotton, 25% Metal |

**Desired Matches**

| Original String | Match |
| --- | --- |
| Leather | name equals Leather |
| Sock Leather | *No Match* |
| 100% Cotton | value equals 100, name equals Cotton |
| 100Cot | value equals 100, name equals Cot |
| 80Cot20Pol | value equals 80, name equals Cot |
| Sock 100 Leather | *No Match* |
| Sock 100% Leather | *No Match* |
| 80 % Polyester, 20 % Cotton | value equals 80, name equals Polyester |
| 5% Cotton, 20% Polyester, 50% Cotton, 25% Metal | value equals 5, name equals Cotton |

In my example i keep getting a match on sock leather although i applied a negative lookbehind.

What am i doing wrong here ?

And at the same time i would want to look into grabbing the second value with a secondary regex when there is several such as:

**Desired Secondary**

| Original String | Match |
| --- | --- |
| 80Cot20Pol | value equals 20, name equals Pol |
| 80 % Polyester, 20 % Cotton | value equals 20, name equals Cotton |
| 5% Cotton, 20% Polyester, 50% Cotton, 25% Metal | value equals 20, name equals Polyester |

Following a desire to get the third, fourth and so on.

How would you approach this in the best way for using group names for the matches with a single "value" and a single "name" while having banned words such as "Sock" (but also have other banned words)

Hope someone can help me on the right path

Comment: So 'sock' is a banned  word that you want to avoid from matches, is it the only word or are there other such words as well (with 'sock' just being an example) ?

Comment: Why you don't filter strings that contains `sock` or other words before trying to split them?

Comment: There is other words as well - would want to get everything caught in the regex and not handle it in code

Comment: Im using this as part of a dynamic system where i in other cases would want to have the word sock included (as i grab that data for something else).

So it would require a massive code addition to allow for various options for each regex being run (i have like 400 regex patterns running on various strings).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the snippet of code that I've pasted below could be written better but I think it does the trick, that too with regex.

Although if we only have a limited set of string formats to deal with we should explore alternatives and avoid using regex as it is an expensive operation, not to mention regex can be hard to interpret at first glance as opposed to more explicitly written code, just my two cents !

```
import re

strings = [
    'Leather',
    'Sock Leather',
    '100% Cotton',
    '100Cot',
    '80Cot20Pol',
    'Sock 100 Leather',
    'Sock 100% Leather',
    '80 % Polyester, 20 % Cotton',
    '5% Cotton, 20% Polyester, 50% Cotton, 25% Metal'
]
pattern = re.compile('(?P<value>[0-9]{1,2}[0]{0,1})?[% ,]*(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]*)')
for string in strings:
    if string.find('Sock') != -1:
        print(f"FOR '{string}'\n\tNo Match\n")
        continue
    print(f"FOR '{string}'")
    grps = [grp.groupdict() for grp in pattern.finditer(string)]
    for grp in grps:
        if not grp['name']:
            continue
        if grp['value']:
            print(f"\t VALUE - {grp['value']},", end=' ')
        if grp['name']:
            print(f"\t NAME - {grp['name']}")
        else:
            print()
    print()
```

Here's the output for reference.
[image]

Comment: I wanted to look into grabbing it from the regex as i alternatively would have 100 coding blocks for various scenarios. Parsing the data through code would have made it easy enough to handle.

Thanks for the suggestion though!